VSCode images: How to add in explorer panel
Forgive my ignorance on something that should be so simple, but how in the world does one upload/transfer an image from the computer into a folder/file(?) to then be used in VS Codes editor  to be copied, transferred or placed into the code itself? The one file does show up with the alt text only; I haven't added any other images yet. They showed us how to use the editor and how to write the codes, but never showed how to actually get an image to work in it. Any help would be amazing!
I have tried everything I know, and that is not much yet.enter image description here

who is They? First learn how HTML works before using it, and what is the difference of local and server html/img files

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

not sure if I understood it correctly, but you can simply copy it into the Folder you have open in VSCode from File Explorer. Just look up the folder in File Explorer where you have your code and copy the image. If you then have it in the same directory then you can use "RavenMystic.png". If you would like to create another Directory just for images, you can use "images/RavenMystic.png". Hope it helps:)
Edit: Also if you right click in your Explorer Panel inside VSCode, you can get to the Folder via "Reveal in Explorer".
